# XPath : How to select tags between nested markup

Tags: xpath

I've the following markup

```
<p>
<strong>title1</strong>
</p>
<p>Content 1</p>
<p>Content 2</p>
<p>
<strong>title2</strong>
</p>
<p>Content 3</p>
<p>Content 4</p>
<p>
<strong>title3</strong>
</p>
```

I need to extract Content1 and content2
I can't find the xpath expression for this.
Thanks

Comment: Show how you tried

Comment: {
    "title": "//p/strong",
    "body": "//p/following-sibling::p"
}

Comment: And what is the problem with your approach?

Comment: That it is selecting all the content tags, I'd need : title1 with contant 1 and 2, and title 2 with 3 and 4